# Mapping and combining multiple json files

Tags: python, json, dictionary, directory

I have two folder that contain multiple json files

first folder is `/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Clean_Team_Data`

second folder is `/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Slate_Logs`

within in first folder is 30 `json` files like this

```
{
  "Team": "ARI",
  "Games": [
    {
      "Date": "2019-03-28",
      "Opponent": "@ LA Dodgers",
      "Results": "L",
      "Score": "12-5",
      "Line": 150,
      "Over_Under": "O",
      "Total": 7,
      "Opponent_Score": 12,
      "Team_Score": 5,
      "Total_Score": 17,
      "Home_Away": "A",
      "players": []
    },
    {
      "Date": "2019-03-29",
      "Opponent": "@ LA Dodgers",
      "Results": "W",
      "Score": "5-4",
      "Line": 155,
      "Over_Under": "O",
      "Total": 7,
      "Team_Score": 5,
      "Opponent_Score": 4,
      "Total_Score": 9,
      "Home_Away": "A",
      "players": []
    }]
```

the second folder contains 218 json files like this

```
[
  {
    "StatID": 2593242,
    "TeamID": 4,
    "PlayerID": 10002075,
    "SeasonType": 1,
    "Season": 2019,
    "Name": "Colin Moran",
    "Team": "PIT",
    "Position": "3B",
    "PositionCategory": "IF",
    "Started": 1,
    "InjuryStatus": null,
    "GameID": 54207,
    "OpponentID": 31,
    "Opponent": "STL",
    "Day": "2019-04-01T00:00:00",
    "DateTime": "2019-04-01T13:05:00",
    "HomeOrAway": "HOME",
    "Games": 1,
    "FantasyPoints": 12,
    "AtBats": 3,
    "Runs": 1,
    "Hits": 2,
    "Singles": 0,
    "Doubles": 1,
    "Triples": 0,
    "HomeRuns": 1,
    "RunsBattedIn": 3,
    "BattingAverage": 0.667,
    "Outs": 1,
    "Strikeouts": 0,
    "Walks": 2,
    "HitByPitch": 0,
    "Sacrifices": 0,
    "SacrificeFlies": 0,
    "GroundIntoDoublePlay": 0,
    "StolenBases": 0,
    "CaughtStealing": 0,
    "OnBasePercentage": 0.8,
    "SluggingPercentage": 2,
    "OnBasePlusSlugging": 2.8,
    "Wins": 0,
    "Losses": 0,
    "Saves": 0,
    "InningsPitchedDecimal": 0,
    "TotalOutsPitched": 0,
    "InningsPitchedFull": 0,
    "InningsPitchedOuts": 0,
    "EarnedRunAverage": 0,
    "PitchingHits": 0,
    "PitchingRuns": 0,
    "PitchingEarnedRuns": 0,
    "PitchingWalks": 0,
    "PitchingStrikeouts": 0,
    "PitchingHomeRuns": 0,
    "PitchesThrown": 0,
    "PitchesThrownStrikes": 0,
    "WalksHitsPerInningsPitched": 0,
    "PitchingBattingAverageAgainst": 0,
    "FantasyPointsFanDuel": 37.7,
    "FantasyPointsDraftKings": 27,
    "WeightedOnBasePercentage": 0.8,
    "PitchingCompleteGames": 0,
    "PitchingShutOuts": 0,
    "PitchingOnBasePercentage": 0,
    "PitchingSluggingPercentage": 0,
    "PitchingOnBasePlusSlugging": 0,
    "PitchingStrikeoutsPerNineInnings": 0,
    "PitchingWalksPerNineInnings": 0,
    "PitchingWeightedOnBasePercentage": 0
  }]
```

I need to iterate over every file in the first folder and **if** the `Date` and the `Team` from the first object match the `Day` and 'Team' from any `dict` in any file from the second folder I want to append that `dict` to the `players` list in the first `dict` and so on until I've gone through every file in the first folder. I've used a nested for loop and it's only be matching one date `2019-08-18` I'm not sure why. I know this isn't the most efficient solution so feel free to propose a more efficient way of doing it.

Here is the code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

path_to_json = '/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Clean_Team_Data'
Game_logs_json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

path_to_json = '/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Slate_Logs'
FPTS_json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

for file in Game_logs_json_files:
    for file_1 in FPTS_json_files:

        with open('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Clean_Team_Data/'+file+'') as json_file:
            team_data = json.load(json_file)

        with open('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Slate_Logs/'+file_1+'') as json_file:
            fantasy_data = json.load(json_file)

            for obj in team_data['Games']:
                for player in fantasy_data:
                    if player['Day'].split('T')[0] == obj['Date'] and player['Team'] == team_data['Team']:
                        obj['players'].append(player)

    with open('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Game_Logs_With_Player_Data/'+file+'', 'w') as my_file:
        json.dump(team_data, my_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I haven't taken care of the date formatting that you need to do create a check for the dates.(I'm assuming that you'll change the code accordingly).

This is just an efficient approach to your problem.

Create a dictionary.
dict_players = {}

Iterate over all the files that contain the player data.
Iterate over the players and for every player do the following

```
for player in players:
    k = date + '%' + team_name
    if dict_players.has_key(k):
        dict_players[k].append(player)
    else:
        dict_players[k] = [player]
```

Now dict_players dictionary will have list of players for the date and team name combination. (`date + '%' + team_name`). And that is exactly what we need while going through the Team data files.

So now we'll go through the game data but for every game's team and date combination we already have the list of players in our dictionary (dict_players). All we need to do is access that.

```
for game in games:
   game['players'] = dict_players[game['date'] + '%' + team]
```

With this you just need to iterate over every file just once. That reduces the time taken by a huge factor.(as compared to nested loops)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

path_to_json = '/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Clean_Team_Data'
Game_logs_json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

path_to_json = '/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Slate_Logs'
FPTS_json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

for file in Game_logs_json_files:
    with open('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Clean_Team_Data/'+file+'') as json_file:
        team_data = json.load(json_file)

    for file_1 in FPTS_json_files:
        with open('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Slate_Logs/'+file_1+'') as json_file:
            fantasy_data = json.load(json_file)

            for obj in team_data['Games']:
                for player in fantasy_data:
                    if player['Day'].split('T')[0] == obj['Date'] and player['Team'] == team_data['Team']:
                        obj['players'].append(player)

    with open('/Users/aus10/Desktop/MLB_Data/Game_Logs_With_Player_Data/'+file+'', 'w') as my_file:
        json.dump(team_data, my_file)
```

Comment: Dang I thought I tried this, but I guess I didn't. This worked!